# EC2 - DNS is Usable for SSH - Not for HTTP

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, http

I have two EC2 instances with security groups set up to allow HTTP on port 80 and SSH on port 22. The second instance is also configured to allow HTTPS on 443.

I can SSH to both instances using the Public DNS name. In a browser, I'm able to view the response from the second instance by navigating to either the IP address or the DNS name. However, the first instance I'm only able to view the response by using the IP address.

Visiting the DNS name in a browser shows an Nginx error - 404 not found.

How can I set up the first instance to respond correctly to requests to the DNS name over HTTP?

If you need additional details, please let me know.

Comment: what do you get in the browser when you visit the first instance by DNS name?  is there any message?

Comment: i'm thinking maybe the HTTP server in the first instance does not have the correct hostname configured.

Comment: @Skaperen I get an nginx error - 404 not found

Comment: Oddly enough - adding support for HTTPS resolved the DNS issue....still not sure why it wouldn't work properly with HTTP.